# Empty XML Nodes

Tags: c#, xml, microsoft-metro

I'm making for my college an application which gathers data out from the XML. Beside the rest of the class am I making this in the Modern UI of Windows 8 which is working great for me except for one little thing.

When I gather the child nodes of a specific node do I get non-existent/empty values with it.
The values I should get are these.

- Hello
- Bye
- Hello World

But what I get into my list view are the following..
(The . means empty)

- .
- Hello
- .
- Bye
- .
- Hello World
- .

The code I use to get the items in the list view is the following.

```
        foreach (IXmlNode Node in XmlFile.SelectSingleNode("XML").SelectSingleNode("List").ChildNodes)
        {
            lvList.Items.Add(Node.InnerText.ToString());
        }
```

How do I get rid of the empty values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lvList = XmlFile.SelectSingleNode("XML")
              .SelectSingleNode("List")
              .ChildNodes
              .Cast<XmlNode>()
              .Select(n => n.InnerText)
              .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
              .ToList();
```

Or:

```
 foreach (IXmlNode Node in XmlFile.SelectSingleNode("XML").SelectSingleNode("List").ChildNodes)
    {
        string nodeText = Node.InnerText;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nodeText))
            lvList.Items.Add(nodeText);
    }
```

Comment: This didn't worked, it appears the field is not really empty.
I tested this with a message box by putting a | before the "empty" node and after it. The result I got from this was a line break between the both the |

Comment: @NiekEsselink: I have edited my answer to use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, try this

Comment: The IsNullOrWhiteSpace fixed the problem. It probably was a field with one or two spaces with a line break between them